# How to change the shape of an onClick highlight?

Tags: android, onclick, icons, highlight

I currently have icons in a GridView on my app. When they are clicked, an orange square appears around them briefly as a highlight. The only problem is that I think this looks amateurish and would like to change the shape so that it clips the icon in the GridView instead of a large square. If you are unsure as to what I mean, it is carried out successfully in the Catch Notes app, on their dashboard/home screen. I was just wondering whether anybody knew a way to tackle this or if it is simply a small layout attribute.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.threebanana.notes&hl=en

Thanks in advance, all help would be appreciated!

It looks effectively like this EditText in the image below. The way that it borders the EditText in orange is exactly how it borders the icons in the home screen when clicked.

[image]

Comment: they are probably using a [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html). Post a screenshot if you can. I won't install a notes program that uses all of those permissions on my own device.

Comment: After carrying out some research. I'm pretty sure that it could be a ColorStateList. Is there any chance you could show me how to implement it for an icon in a GridView? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided that the easiest way to solve this problem is to simply reference another image when the image on the GridView has been clicked. This means that the second image can just be edited in Photoshop in order to have a glow around it.

Answer (score 3):

First, in your layout file, specify a **drawable background**:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_your_view"
```

Then edit the **bg_your_view** file which is in drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_your_view_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_your_view_normal" android:state_focused="false"></item>
</selector>
```

At last, create corresponding drawable files for **pressed** and **normal** states:

- **bg_your_view_pressed.xml** contains the shape, the color you want for highlight.
- **bg_your_view_normal.xml** is similar, just without highlight effect.

Comment: I've used an image selector already. I then have tow images, the normal one and the pressed one with the highlight that I added in Photoshop. Thanks for your answer anyway though.