# Animation While Setting Background Drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-animation

I have a textView, which displays some name, say (**Harley**), then on click of a button, i am setting background of **Harley** as a drawable shape and also it's color.
It's all working fine.

I want to apply an animation while background is being set, it should appear as if while setting the background it's scaling up.

I tried using scale animation on the textView, but no luck.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

I have solved this problem, by applying **ScaleAnimation** after drawable is set to the textView.

```
ScaleAnimation mScaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.5f);
        mScaleAnimation.setDuration(500);

 viewRoboto.clearAnimation();
 viewRoboto.setAnimation(mScaleAnimation);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**TransitionDrawable in Android**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) for achieveing such functionality. Also take a look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35439717/2450855)

Answer (score 1):

Better use of [Property Animation Api](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) this worked for me

```
int colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
int colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.setDuration(250); // milliseconds
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        textView.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
    }

});
colorAnimation.start();
```

Comment: Okay, so it might work if i am changing color. What if i am just changing the background shape of my textView, will it work in that scenario.

Comment: @Ritesh for that check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131005/how-to-change-the-shape-of-an-onclick-highlight

Comment: That is a very diffn scenario, i have a drawable rectangle shape, when clicked on a button, it is set the the textView background. What I am trying to do here is, while setting the shape drawable as background of textView, it should emerge out from device as if it's coming out of screen from small size to it's original size.